# What is the difference between the usage of "nevertheless" and "nonetheless"

Tags: word-usage

*1. Statements which, although literally true, are ___________ misleading.*

*2. It was the barest of welcomes, but it was a welcome ____________.*

Google dictionary says that "nevertheless" should be used in the first sentence and "nonetheless" should be used in the second one. The meaning of "nonetheless" is given as:

> in spite of that; nevertheless.

Does this mean that both the words can be used interchangeably? For some reason "nonetheless misleading" seems inappropriate. Can someone please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between them is that *nevertheless* is more appropriate in reference to *events* or things that might 'never' happen, whereas *nonetheless* is more appropriate in reference to measurable, quantifiable things that you could say there is 'none' of.

For example:

> He did not want to leave. Nevertheless, he did.

'Leaving' is an *event* that could or could not (never) happen.

> He did not like musicals, but he enjoyed the production nonetheless.

This comments on *how much* he enjoyed something, a measurable amount.

I feel that both your examples require '*nonetheless*'. The first is asking whether *something* is more or less misleading than something else, so it is about measurement. Likewise, the second example compares two kinds of welcome, and says one was no less of a welcome than the other.

Comment: Grammarist - https://grammarist.com/compound-words/nevertheless-vs-nonetheless/